# Add Conditions in Select Many using Linq

Tags: c#, .net

I have the below code

```
 var reportQuery = new Func<IQueryable<Bid>, IEnumerable<ApprovalRequestDashboardVM>>(bids =>
                            {                                
                                return Bid.GetScopeAndPricingDependencies(bids).SelectMany(bid =>
                                {
                                    var bidWorkflowApprovalValues = bid.ApprovalWorkflows.Values.Where(a => a.StatusHasAlwaysBeenNotEffective == false)
                                                                       .OrderBy(a => a.Name)
                                                                       .ThenBy(a => a.Node.NodeType)
                                                                       .ThenBy(a => a.Node.NodeName);
                                    return bidWorkflowApprovalValues.SelectMany(aw =>
                                    {
                                        return aw.StatusHistory.Where(history => filterApprovalStatus.Count() > 0 ? filterApprovalStatus.Contains(history.StatusID) : true).Select(history =>
                                        {
                                            return new ApprovalRequestDashboardVM()
                                            {
                                                ApprovalID = aw.ApprovalID,
                                                ApprovalName = aw.Name,
                                                BidID = bid.BidID,
                                                BidVersionNumber = bid.BidVersionNumber,
                                                BidStatus = bid.Status,
                                                ApprovalStatus = history.Status,
                                                StatusDate = history.StatusDate,


                                            };
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
```

I am trying to filter out the bids based on certain condition

```
   public bool AllApprovalWorkflowsApproved()
        {
            if (this.ApprovalWorkflows.Values.Where(x => x.Status == ApprovalStatus.Reviewing).Count() > 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }
```

So if the ApprovalStatus has Reviweing then I don't want the bid to be processed.

If I add this to the query

`bids = bids.Where(x => x.AllApprovalWorkflowsApproved());` to make sure only the bids which have no workflows in Reviewing Status then I get an error that EF is not able to convert my method to store expression.

Can someone please tell me how I can filter the data inside SelectMany

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] array =
        {
            "king",
            "queen",
            "throne"
        };

        var result = array.SelectMany(element => element.ToCharArray())
            .Where(RemoveLetterTSpec)
            .Where(RemoveLetterESpec);

        foreach (char letter in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(letter);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static bool RemoveLetterESpec(char arg)
    {
        return arg != 'e';
    }

    private static bool RemoveLetterTSpec(char arg)
    {
        return arg != 't';
    }
}
```

this is a simple example on how to filter on SelectMany